# Image import in Haxe / OpenFL

Tags: haxe, openfl

I want to import an image using Haxe, my image is big but it is 8 bits and it weighs 89kb. The problem occurs when I import it, because the size of the memory grows by 35mb. I suppose it is reserving memory for a 32bit image.
Any idea how to import an image of 8bits, without consuming so much memory?

Comment: What APIs are you using for this?  What's your output target?  Can you provide a minimal yet reproduceable example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenFL currently uses 32-bit memory for images at runtime, regardless of the original compression format. I believe there is an enhancement task open right now to allow for 24-bit, 16-bit and other color formats.